# Reporting Snapshot did not create a record?

Tags: reporting, snapshot, analytic-snapshots

All,

I set up a simple Reporting Snapshot for a client that pulls in Opportunities closed the previous month. It triggered on time as it should but a snapshot object record did not get created. Upon review, the source report had queried 0 records as there were no closed Won opportunities in February.

So the question is - if a Source report for Reporting Snapshots returns 0 records, why doesn't a record in the target object get created showing 0s in the relevant fields.

I've used Reporting Snapshots before but never had the 0 records scenario. Since this is used to build a trendline by month I don't want there to be a month missing so I added the record manually.

Comment: is this a summary report?

Comment: Yes. I have set up a handful of Reporting Snapshots recently and was just looking to replicate one of them. I was assuming we'd get a record with 0 entries.